# Once per client validation for WHMCS promocode

Tags: whm, whmcs

I am using WHMCS API and I have created promotions, For one of my promotions, it is needed to have onceperclient setting activated. But how can I check it in the backend..? How do I know whether the promotion is already applied by the client..? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your database — phpmyadmin for example, you can check your database tables for the module/plugin datafields and they will show you the list of clients using your promotions. It will probably have their username email with values containing **0** for **not active**, and **1** for **active**.

That's where I would start first.